# How to get help for Erlang functions from the Elixir shell

Tags: erlang, elixir

In iex, I can not get help for built-in Erlang functions, for example:

```
iex(1)> h :lists.reverse
:lists was not compiled with docs
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I don't think so since Erlang documentation is completely different from Elixir documentation. Probably you're better off browsing it [online](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html)?

Comment: Well, it would be awfully nice if the Elixir shell also knew how to show me Erlang documentation then!

Comment: It would mean implementing the whole documentation parsing and processing feature though, so it may not be worth it.

Comment: Not really an answer I guess but try h(Enum.reverse).  On the point of "it would be nice if the Elixir shell also knew how . . ."--they do accept pull requests you know. I'd guess they consider there are other higher priorities right now but I'm sure they wouldn't mind it if someone figured out how to make this work.

Answer (score 7):

**No. There is not.**

Erlang documentation is different than Elixir documentation. As @whatyouhide said, it would mean writing an Erlang documentation parser and wiring it into `h/1` in the console. While not impossible it would take some work. As far as I know no one is working on doing this.

As @Onorio Catenacci said, they do accept PR's so you (or someone else) could change this :).

Comment: FWIW, I do have  a PR and code that supports this for any Erlang installation that has man pages installed. https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/pull/3640 and https://github.com/bbense/erlman

Answer (score 4):

As others have pointed out, there is no easy way to do this from within Elixir. However, here are some short-cuts, which might be useful for inspecting the functions available in Erlang modules from iex (even though none of this actually gives access to any documentation).

### What functions are provided by a given Erlang module?

To list all functions exported by an Erlang module, use the `module_info` function, e.g:

```
Enum.each :lists.module_info(:exports), &IO.inspect/1
```

This prints a list of function names and their arity.

### What arguments does an Erlang function accept?

To get a rough idea, you can print spec information for Erlang functions from iex using the `s` command:

```
iex(1)> s :lists.reverse
@spec reverse(list1, tail) :: list2 when List1: [t], Tail: term(), List2: [t], T: term(), list1: var, tail: var, list2: var
@spec reverse(list1) :: list2 when List1: [t], List2: [t], T: term(), list1: var, list2: var
```

Of course, looking up the on-line documentation is probably the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a module that attempts provide as much erlang documentation as possible from the unix man pages that get installed with erlang on unix systems.

https://github.com/philosophers-stone/ehelper

Example in use:

```
iex(3)> e :lists.reverse

                             :lists.reverse(list1)

### reverse(List1) -> List2

Types:

List1 = List2 = [T]

T = term()

Returns a list with the elements in List1 in reverse order.


                          :lists.reverse(list1, tail)

### reverse(List1, Tail) -> List2

Types:

List1 = [T]

Tail = term()

List2 = [T]

T = term()

Returns a list with the elements in List1 in reverse order, with tail Tail
appended.

Example:

    > lists:reverse([1, 2, 3, 4], [a, b, c]).
    [4,3,2,1,a,b,c]
```